# vue preset.json vue create message

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a vue project with :

vue create --preset ./ my-app

preset.json is

```
{
    "useTaobaoRegistry": true,
    "packageManager": "npm",
    "presets": {
      "preset1": {
        "useConfigFiles": true,
        "plugins": {
          "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": {},
          "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": {},
          "@vue/cli-plugin-router": {
            "historyMode": true
          },
          "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": {},
          "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": {
            "config": "base",
            "lintOn": [
              "save"
            ]
          },
          "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": {},
          "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": {}
        },
        "cssPreprocessor": "dart-sass"
      }
    }
  }
```

When I execute this command, I get the following error

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot set property '@vue/cli-service' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property '@vue/cli-service' of undefined
    at Creator.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Creator.js:97:40)
    at async create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/create.js:72:3)
```

Is it an error of preset json?

Comment: Looks like some option is missing? Can you traceback what 'of undefined' is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install all dependencies with one of this commands:

`yarn install`

or

`npm install`

looks like you did not install all dependencies of your project so '@vue/cli-service' is not found.